# Implementing a Hit-And-Run MCMC Sampler in Python

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I'm trying to implement the *Metropolisized Hit-And-Run Sampler* as described in Chapter 7.2 of *Chen and Schmeiser, Performance of the Gibbs, Hit-and-Run, and Metropolis Samplers* https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1390645.pdf

I chose the function $g$ to be a piecewise constant distribution function based on evaluations of the log probability along the direction of movement.

It seems that the chain does not converge to the posterior distribution. I particular both mean and standard deviation of the produced samples are smaller than the true values.

Here's my python implementation. Am I missing something? I haven't found a working version of this sampler anywhere.

```py
import numpy as np

# test log probability
def logprob(x):
    return - 0.5*np.sum((x-5.0)**2.0)

x0 = np.array([-1.0,-1.0]) # Initial point
nsteps = 50000 # Number of steps
ndim = 2 # Number of dimensions


# Piecewise constant density g
def gfunc(logprob,x0,d,lmax=1.0,npieces=2):

    dl = 2. * lmax / npieces  # Compute width of piecewise constant regions
    # Compute centres of those regions
    centres = np.linspace(x0-(npieces-1.0)/2.0*dl*d,x0+(npieces-1.0)/2.0*dl*d,npieces)

    logprobvals = list(map(logprob,centres)) # Evaluate the logprob at those points
    probvals = np.exp(logprobvals) # Get the probability
    gvals = probvals / np.sum(probvals) # Normalise the probability to sum to 1

    piece = np.random.choice(np.arange(-int(npieces/2),int(npieces/2)),p=gvals) # Choose a random region with probability goals

    gprime = gvals[int(npieces/2)+piece] # Compute g(x0+l*d)

    l = np.random.uniform(piece*dl, (piece+1)*dl, size=ndim) # Uniformly sample l from that region

    return l, gprime


x = np.empty((nsteps,ndim)) # Initialise array to save samples
g = np.empty((nsteps)) # Initialise array to save g evaluations
g[-1] = 0.1 # This is arbitrary
x[-1] = x0
for i in range(nsteps):
    d = np.random.normal(0,1,size=ndim) # Compute unit direction vector
    d /= np.linalg.norm(d)

    l, gp = gfunc(logprob,x[i-1],d,lmax=5.0,npieces=100) # Sample l and get g(x0+l*d)
    ratio = g[i-1]/gp # Compute g/g' ratio to be used in M-H acceptance criterion

    Z = x[i-1] + l * d # Compute new point

    # Check Metropolis-Hastings acceptance criterion
    if np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0) <= min(1.0, ratio * np.exp(logprob(Z)-logprob(x[i-1]))): # Accept
        x[i] = Z
        g[i] = gp
    else: # Reject
        x[i] = x[i-1]
        g[i] = g[i-1]
```

**Update**

Here are the produced Markov chains and samples respectively:
[image: Markov Chains]
[image: Last 2500 out 5000 samples]

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you did? For example, what's your target density?

Comment: Also, a thought experiment (and a unit test to implement): what is the integral of your $g$ on the whole real line, and what should it be?

Comment: Is your gfunc drawing a sample, or returning a representation of the whole function, or something else?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you post a plot of the samples it's generating? Hopefully colored by $i$?

Comment: I just added the plots. The target density is a 2D Normal distribution of mean (5,5) and unit variance (i.e. see logprob function).

Comment: gfunc is computing the p(x) along the line and returns a) a sample, and b) the value of g at the new point (This is needed for the M-H acceptance criterion).

Comment: I think the integral of g along $\mathcal{R}^{1}$ should (and I think it is) 1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that your $g$ depends on $x_i$. Your source says "We now require that $g$ depend on $x_i$ only through the line segment $S_i$." But your $g$ is basically completely flexible; if you were to plot $\lambda$ versus $g(\lambda)$, it could be different with every new point sampled.

Comment: This make sense! I tried using different definitions of $g$ that depend on $x_{i}$ only through the line segment $S_{i}$, but I fail to find a proper working one. In particular, the main difficulty is constructing a general proposal $g$ that returns consistent values for $g(x_{i})$ in the current point using the previous line segment (i.e. $g_{i-1}(x_{i-1}+\lambda_{i-1}\vec{d}_{i-1})$) and the proposed one (i.e. $g_{i}(x_{i})$). Since the current point is the intersection of the previous line $g$ and the current $g$ one, the two of them should agree, right?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right way to say $g$ should depend on $S_i$ but not $x_i$. I would say you want $g_{x_{i-1}, d}(y) = g_{x_i, d}(y)$ for all $y$ and $d$. (Note I keep the direction the same; it's $d$ and not $d_i$.)

Comment: This seems weird and hard to construct though. I may have understood wrong.

Comment: Can you just somehow choose your grid points without reference to $x_i$? Like a permanently fixed grid?